# How to identify photoshop-edited files

Tags: photoshop, photo-editing, jpeg, image-manipulation

If I have saved an image in JPG format after doing some edits, is there a way to identify that it is edited with Photoshop?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

it depends what you're looking for.

1) **File Meta-info**: the meta information contained within the file can reveal which s/w saved the photo last (with possible edits). But this can easily be changed afterwards or deleted by another s/w.

2) **Image data**: now, if you're looking to find out if a photo file has been tempered (edits made to it), you should look into *Error Level Analysis* and *photo forensics*.

[errorlevelanalysis.com](http://www.errorlevelanalysis.com), [hackerfactor.com](http://www.hackerfactor.com/) and other such software are only made available to governments!

Comment: Also see this question: [Software that guesses which algorithm saved a given JPEG](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/71703/software-that-guesses-which-algorithm-saved-a-given-jpeg)

Answer (score 4):

It's easу. Photoshop CAN write its name into the **EXIF Software** tag, so you can locate images that have been edited by Photoshop using any photo management program that can locate images by the EXIF Software tag:

[image]

However, if you save your images as JPEG using **File > Save for Web** option (Ctrl + Shift + Alt + S) make sure that you checked the option below:

[image]

otherwise you will not be able to identify your images later by EXIF/XMP Software tags.

Comment: What if I modify the EXIF to specifically not note that the software was photoshop? How can you then tell that it was or was not edited in photoshop?

Comment: Not by EXIF/XMP software tags, but yes by other means, known colloquially as "I can haz see d pixelz". :) (plus, what dpollitt said.)

Comment: Simple check, even when No EXIF is selected open the file in a hex editor and the first few lines include 'Adobe'.

Comment: I tried just now, and I ws able to to edit the file and substitute another word, such as "ScanJet", for "Adobe", in the file and the image was still valid. But when I tried to put in larger data it corrupted the image.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this [web site](http://fotoforensics.com/).
It analyses the picture, so you don't need the EXIF data.

Answer (score -1):

Some photo editing software also add the name of the editor into the file. So it would look like this

```
EXtSoftware\x00Paint.NET v3.5.11
```

And it would be in the middle of the file.

Comment: Looking into the file meta info is already part of the accepted answer.