# Software that guesses which algorithm saved a given JPEG

Tags: software, jpeg

Some time ago, I found a piece of software that would provide a good guess on the software/algorithm used to save a JPEG.

If I recall correctly, it would analyze something like the compression artifacts and compare it against a known database. The result allowed to know if the JPEG was a result of specific cameras (ie: Canon Powershot A560) or image processing software (ie: Photoshop CS 8.0).
Note that it would *not* read exif information.

**What software was this?**

Is it still around?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try [JPEGSnoop](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jpegsnoop/):

> JPEGsnoop is a detailed JPEG image decoder and analysis tool. It reports all image metadata and can even help identify if an image has been edited.

As explained on [the JPEGSnoop webpage](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/jpeg-snoop.html):

> One of the latest features in JPEGsnoop is an internal database that compares an image against a large number of compression signatures. JPEGsnoop reports what digital camera or software was likely used to generate the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Amped Authenticate](http://ampedsoftware.com/authenticate), which has a richer and user customizable database. It is not a free software, but a professional tool used by law enforcement and forensic labs worldwide. (Disclaimer: I am the company CEO and founder.)